# Making a Div container load by coming in vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Could I set an onload function with jQuery, that allowed a div container to load coming in the page vertically from the top to the position?

I have a simple tabbed website, that loads the content in a div container - I think it would be awesome to have this container load by easing from the top of the screen, to the position.

Any suggestions on how to do this with my already container, as opposed to recreated with a jQuery /CSS tabbed plugin?

Comment: Show us the HTML that you want to animate and describe in a little more detail how you want the animation to work and I'm sure we could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think jQuery [slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) should help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the .slideDown() after the div loads or do you want it to load while its sliding?
http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/